# How to integrate this product of Exp[] and Cos[] using Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like to integrate the following product of `Exp` and `Cos`：

```
Integrate[Exp[-a x^2 + b x] Cos[x t], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

But the output is the same as the input form.  Is it possible for Mathematica to perform this integration?

Comment: `Integrate[Exp[-a x^2 + b x] Cos[x t], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> t > 0 && a > 0 && b > 0]`

Comment: Obviously a has to be greater zero, t needs to be real, and there are no restrictions on b.

Comment: Less restrictive assumptions, faster too: `res = Integrate[Exp[-a x^2 + b x] Cos[x t] // TrigToExp, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> a > 0]`.  And `res // ExpToTrig // TrigExpand // Simplify` gives a nice looking result.

Comment: If you wait, this gives a result with a condition for integrability: `Integrate[
 Exp[-a x^2 + b x] Cos[x t] // TrigToExp, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides of the method provide by @Michael E2,we can test the result by N-L formula.

```
int = Integrate[Exp[-a x^2 + b x] Cos[x t], x, Assumptions -> a > 0]
expr = Limit[int, x -> ∞, Assumptions -> a > 0] - 
  Limit[int, x -> -∞, Assumptions -> a > 0]
Simplify[expr // ComplexExpand, a > 0]
```

[image]

The same as

```
Assuming[a > 0, 
 Integrate[
    Exp[-a x^2 + b x] Cos[x t] // TrigToExp, {x, -∞,∞}] // ComplexExpand // Simplify]
```

Comment: Why   this code does not work well?    Integrate[Exp[-a x^2 + b x] Cos[x t], {x, -Infinity, Infinity},  Assumptions -> a > 0] // ComplexExpand // Simplify